# Oracle Universal Installer: Install completes, but in (Not responding) state

Tags: oracle, installation, oracle-12c

I am running the universal installer for 64-bit ODAC 12c Release 1 (12.1.0.1.0) for Windows x64 on Windows Server 2012 R2 box. Screenshot of Oracle version below.

I have completed the installer properly many times, but this time I have run the installer with correct parameters (this has been a repetitive task) and the installer completes, except in **(Not Responding)** state.

I have checked the logs here `C:\Program Files\Oracle\Inventory\logs` and the last line looks as my other successful installs.

```
INFO: no. of sets of tools to be run: 0 
INFO: ca page to be shown: false
INFO: exitonly tools to be excuted passed: 0
INFO: 
*** End of Installation Page***
The installation of Oracle Data Access Components for Oracle Client was successful.
```

[image]

[image]

Did this in fact mean that Oracle has installed correctly?

Comment: I was able to successfully run sqlplus from cmd prompt -  `select dual from sysdate` and got back an expected response.. This is needed for my app, so I will know soon if installation is good or not.. otherwise, I need to remove everything Oracle and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the setup was not complete. I needed to [remove everything Oracle].[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83967/how-do-i-do-a-manual-uninstall-of-oracle) and reinstall.

Once that was completed, I ran the installer again, and it completed successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if there is a modal window that is under your current installer window that is waiting for you to click finished/done...

Comment: I would give the same answer. I had such problem twice installing Oracle 12c and there was a window hidden under main installer. Try Alt+Tab to find if there is other window. @AndrewWilliamRoss

Comment: No windows are open under the installer fellas..